# Creating a URL that goes to a specific point on a webpage

Tags: url

I've been reading up about links that can take you to a *div id* on a site, eg:

www.example.com/#halfwaydownpage

I'm trying to do create a link that will jump to a position on a site, however there are very few *div id* elements in the code.

Has anyone heard of another method of achieving this that doesn't use *div id*?

Answer (score 1):

If you are linking to your own website (meaning: you can edit the source as you need), or to some other website where named anchors are already present, you can do like so:

```html
<a href="#ipsum2">ipsum II</a>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
<p>sic dolor</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><a name="ipsum2"></a>ipsum ipsum</p>
```

otherwise, linking to a point in a page where a named div resides, you need assistive javascript to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I can't amend the website, I'd just like to link people to the relevant section on it. I can't see any tags going by <a name="sample"> either. Good to know for another time though, thanks.

Comment: @joebody'sbusiness that was exactly my point, if you can't edit the linked website, either it offers some kind of its own anchoring, or you can't do much, either than writing, say, "scroll to about two thirds of the page" :D